# Installing a file as part of making an ISO installer

Tags: rhel

I am sure that this is answered somewhere else on this board, but I have searched high and low and have been unable to find an answer.

I am building a custom ISO installer and everything is going quite well, but I need to cat my SSL certificate on each installation.

What I am wondering is how I install an individual file from my ISO specifically onto my installed system. I will give the exact filepath that I have setup for my ISO, but the file itself just sits on the disc and doesn't go into the install because I haven't told it to do so.

File path is:
isolinux/certs/ca.pem

How do I get this onto the installed linux system so that I can run:
cat ca.pem >> /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt

Thanks for any and all help.

Comment: Is there a reason you're not doing this with kickstart?

Comment: Also, what RHEL version?

Comment: RHEL version 7.  I have a kickstart file (It's already highly customized), I don't really want to add the entire certificate into the kickstart file. I'd like to have a file added into the installed system and then cat that onto the ca-bundle.crt. If I have to put the entire cert into the kickstart I guess I could.